# grunt and bower on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs, bower

Today I wanted to deploy my `node.js` application to heroku. Locally I am using `bower` and `grunt` for development also and I wanted to still use them.

Now, following some advice I found on the web I added `bower` to my `dependencies` and added `"postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/bower install` to my `package.json` `postinstall`.

Now I am having some problems with `grunt`. When I move my grunt dependencies to `dependencies` from `devDependencies` `grunt` does not recognize my `tasks`, for example when I have

```
    {
      "name": "js-linkedin-connector",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "passport": "~0.1.17",
        "passport-local": "~0.1.6",
        "passport-linkedin-oauth2": "~1.0.1",
        "connect": "~2.11.0",
        "underscore": "~1.5.2",
        "bower": "1.2.x",
        "grunt": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-cli": "0.1.11",
        "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.1.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
        "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
        "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
        "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
        "grunt-concurrent": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-jasmine-node": "~0.1.0",
        "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
        "time-grunt": "~0.1.0",
        "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
        "connect-livereload": "~0.3.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.3",
        "karma-requirejs": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.0",
        "karma": "~0.10.4",
        "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.8.0",
        "npm": "1.3.x"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "grunt test",
        "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/bower install;node_modules/.bin/grunt server:dist"
      }
    }
```

in my `package.json` when I type `./node_modules/.bin/grunt` I am getting:

```
Warning: Task "jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

But when I move `grunt` dependencies to `devDependencies`:

```
    {
      "name": "js-linkedin-connector",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "passport": "~0.1.17",
        "passport-local": "~0.1.6",
        "passport-linkedin-oauth2": "~1.0.1",
        "connect": "~2.11.0",
        "underscore": "~1.5.2",
        "bower": "1.2.x"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-cli": "0.1.11",
        "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.1.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
        "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
        "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
        "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
        "grunt-concurrent": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-jasmine-node": "~0.1.0",
        "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
        "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
        "time-grunt": "~0.1.0",
        "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
        "connect-livereload": "~0.3.0",
        "karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.3",
        "karma-requirejs": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.0",
        "karma": "~0.10.4",
        "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.8.0",
        "npm": "1.3.x"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "grunt test",
        "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/bower install;node_modules/.bin/grunt server:dist"
      }
    }
```

everything works fine.

What is the problem and how can I resolve it to deploy my `grunt` + `bower` app to heroku?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep your Grunt dependencies in `devDependencies`, where they belong. Use a [custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to allow Heroku to execute your Grunt flow on their platform.

[Sample app that shows how to do exactly that](https://github.com/buildfirst/heroku-grunt)

Buildpacks let you fire up the app differently, in this case you'll want to change it from the config settings:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt.git
```

Then it's just a matter of adding a `heroku` task to your Grunt configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look later today.

Comment: I followed your advice of using this buildpack and everything works fine, application deployed correctly :), thanks.

Comment: @Nico can you elaborate on leaving them in devDependencies "where they belong"? It seems like if you need them on your production service, they are no longer a dev dependency. The buildpack that you referenced recommends putting grunt into dependencies as well.

Comment: @Nico Thanks.  I was trolling SO today and this solved my issue as well.  +1 and anytime you are in  Minneapolis I have your first beer.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Had to move grunt an bower to dependencies rather than dependencies. More here: https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt/issues/5

Comment: The official buildback has been updated. The instructions on the following page worked for me: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I've tried some methods to make sure what works and what does not for me. I needed to minify my scripts with uglify.

1. First, I added grunt and grunt-contrib-uglify to my devDependencies (as I develop on my machine), and tried the "postinstall" script in package.json:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "start": "node index.js",
     "postinstall": "grunt uglify"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "grunt": "~0.4.4",
     "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0"
   }
   ```

   this obviously did not work, because heroku does not install devDependencies.
2. after this, I set up the buildpack, added a heroku task to my Gruntfile.js, removed the postinstall script and tried to push.

   This was also unsuccessful, because the buildpack only installed grunt-cli and grunt, but not grunt-contrib-uglify.
3. next I moved grunt & grunt-contrib-uglify to dependencies from devDependencies. (if I move uglify, why should I not move grunt). This way it worked, but made me feel: why do I need the buildpack, if I have to add grunt to dependencies?
4. I've reverted to the default buildpack

   ```
   heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL
   ```

   and added the postinstall script mentioned above. this was not working, because the grunt command was still missing.
5. finally, I also added grunt-cli to dependencies, and it works now, without the buildpack!

Conclusion: you do not need the buildpack - and add your grunt dependencies to "dependencies". 
Or, the buildpack should fix this issue: https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt/issues/5